# Execute a command every minute forever using 'date'

Tags: bash, scripting, cron, date

I'm looking for a way (`bash` script or other) to make a command run every minute using `date` - I've been looking around for similar solutions but they all suggest either `cron` or `watch` but what I want to do is to execute the command according to the output of `date` so that I could make the command run when the second hand hits 30, example 
12:50:30
12:51:30
12:52:30
12:53:30
...
any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
until [[ $(date +%S) -eq 30 ]]
do
  sleep 0.75
done

while true
do
  #command & 
  #here your cmds should be forked to background to avoid delaying
  date +%S
  sleep 30
done
```

### edit

as you wanted to see date +%S stdout and check if = 30 and execute somthing!

```
#!/bin/bash
foo(){
  echo yay
  #add commands here
}
while true
do
  date +%S | grep '30' && foo 
  sleep 1
done
```

### or

```
#!/bin/bash
foo(){
  echo yay
  #add commands here
}
while true
do
  date +%S
  [[ $(date +%S) -eq 30 ]] && foo 
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Any idea what causes this? "trigger.sh: line 2: [[: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")" 
Also I want the command to be triggered according to 'date' not to 'sleep 30'

Comment: Basically I want 'date +%S' to be executed every second and when the output is "30" the main command gets executed and so on.

Comment: Simply brilliant and clean - does exactly what's intended.

Comment: i'm glad that it works!